# PHP Include changes layout of HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

This is my index.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "top.html";
include "main.html";
include "bottom.html";
?>
```

Nothing special as you can see, and will be subject to change ;)

And this is my `HTML` code (don't mind the text, it makes no sense at all, I was just bored and wrote some blindtext myself)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <div id="container"> 
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="menu">
                <p>
                Link1
                Link2
                Link3
                Link4
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="content">

        <!-- end of top.html -->

                <h2>Ernährungsphysiologische Bedeutung von Transfetten</h2>
                <p>
                Transfette, verdammt auf alle Ewigkeit, verschrien weil sie Krebs verursachen, verkannt, sind sie doch so nahrhaft, wertvoll und unersetzlich in unserer täglichen Ernährung.<br>
                Was die wenigsten Menschen wissen, ist, dass die Herstellung von Transfetten schon auf die Ureinwohner Sumatras zurückgreift, die in ihren Voodooritualen mithilfe von Schweinehaut diese Leckerei herstellten.
                Damals noch ein seltenes Gut, hauptsächlich innerhalb religiöser Riten verwendet, ist es auch noch heute eine Spezialität, die nur die wenigsten Gourmets unserer Zeit wirklich zu schätzen wissen.
                </p>
                <p>
                Doch wo kommen diese Transfette eigentlich her? Hauptsächlich werden sie heutzutage gewonnen indem man altes Fritierfett filtert und die alten Pommesreste aus dem Filter dann in eine Ölpresse wirft. Kaltgepresste Transfette sind dabei die seltensten aber auch gleichzeitig die schmackhaftesten Produkte, das Pommesöl ist natürlich auch gesund, aber existiert in so großen Mengen, dass man damit lieber seine Schweine füttern sollte, damit das Schnitzel auch ohne Bratfett in der Pfanne zubereitet werden kann.
                </p>
                <p>
                Haben wir sie überzeugt? Möchten sie Transfette in rauhen Mengen kaufen?<br />
                Schreiben sie uns! Wir freuen uns auf ihre Bestellung.
                </p>

        <!-- end of main.html -->

            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                this smells like footer
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So if I only include this whole thing as `main.html` and leave the other files blank, everything is fine, but when I split up the code (at the postitions I marked) into the designated files... Strange things happen.

A picture tells more than thousand words, so here you go:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of browser you are using? I'm sure his name is IE :)

Comment: naw, firefox in this case... but i try to test my pages on different browsers, so IE aswell (haven't done that yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [the comments in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.include.php#95276) this might be a file encoding problem. setting it to utf-8 should help.

Comment: oh my god, yeah that was it ... i feel stupid, for not thinking of that, haha :) index.php was ANSI and all php files were utf-8. i now set them to utf-8 w/o BOM and it looks different to the original, but it looks the same in both cases. will accept the answer as soon as i can (5 min left)

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with whitespace in the file, some times whitespace changes the way websites render, and that can happen when you include seprate files with PHP, it can cause extra whitespace in the source code of the HTML causing the render errors.

Answer (score 0):

You structuring of your HTML document can become hard to manage. You do not need to call an include, which it shouldn't be.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You should try calling:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

This will stop all error reporting which may prevent disruption with your template. But the ini_set was not necessary.

Comment: It is necessary to make sure global settings of `display_errors` are switched on, however some PHP have them turned off by default, like MAMP for Mac, so I use `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` then the `error_reporting(E_ALL)` since it's useful to debug PHP problems ;)

Comment: this error reporting stuff is just something i copied off a tutorial. was a recommendation, so i did ;) @tjmoore i dont get why the include is not needed? i want to switch the content of main.html later by using the menu, so some kind of include has to be there i think...

Answer (score -1):

The important thing is to set the encoding of include files to UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM. Otherwise there's an invisible code added to the include file which the browser interprets as some white space resulting in a displaced layout.